# Appium throws "ideviceinstaller" not found when launched through Eclipse - Java

Tags: java, eclipse, mobile, appium

I observed a weird behavior for Appium to launch from GUI compared with Eclipse (Java)Using Latest Appium v1.3.7

1) PlainNote.app is built and run from Xcode for my Mobile Device. App is launched on real mobile without any issue.

2) Now, through Appium GUI, I was able to launch the same app by providing bundle id, udid, etc. No issues at all

3) The issue comes now when I'm launching an app from Eclipse. Followed standard set of code (i.e. deisred cap, new iosdriver, etc).

Appium is initated through Eclipse console but upon launching it throws below error

```
:-[36minfo[39m: [debug] Couldn't find ideviceinstaller, trying built-in at /Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/build/libimobiledevice-macosx/ideviceinstaller

[31merror[39m: Could not initialize ideviceinstaller; make sure it is installed and works on your system
```

4) If I go to terminal and type ideviceinstaller, it successfully launched below details

```
Prashants-MacBook-Pro:
~ prash$ ideviceinstallerERROR: No mode/operation was supplied.Usage: ideviceinstaller OPTIONSManage apps on iOS devices. -u, --udid UDID Target specific device by its 40-digit device UDID. -l, --list-apps List apps, possible options: -o list_user - list user apps only (this is the default) -o list_system - list system apps only -o list_all - list all types of apps -o xml - print full output as xml plist -i, --install ARCHIVE Install app from package file specified by ARCHIVE. ARCHIVE can also be a .ipcc file for carrier bundles. -U, --uninstall APPID Uninstall app specified by APPID. -g, --upgrade ARCHIVE Upgrade app from package file specified by ARCHIVE. -L, --list-archives List archived applications, possible options: -o xml - print full output as xml plist -a, --archive APPID Archive app specified by APPID, possible options: -o uninstall - uninstall the package after making an archive -o app_only - archive application data only -o docs_only - archive documents (user data) only -o copy=PATH - copy the app archive to directory PATH when done -o remove - only valid when copy=PATH is used: remove after copy -r, --restore APPID Restore archived app specified by APPID -R, --remove-archive APPID Remove app archive specified by APPID -o, --options Pass additional options to the specified command. -h, --help prints usage information -d, --debug enable communication debugging
```

I'm kindof not sure whats happening here! Am I missing on any configuration or have I duplicated idevicecontroller...

This issue is very weird but unfortunately I'm just stuck :(Please guide.

Answer (score 1):

In step #4, where is it finding ideviceinstaller?  You can use the following:

```
which ideviceinstaller
```

If it finding the Appium.app one, try installing ideviceinstaller manually.

```
brew install --HEAD ideviceinstaller
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. It doesn't show the appium path for the above command. However, I still suspect that since Appium is initiated from Eclipse - it redirects to GUI version of Appium and unfortunately it ends up using Appium provided ideviceinstaller. If I remove Appium GUI version, start Appium server from terminal and then simple execute from Eclipse (without starting Appium server) then it works perfectly.