# Running appium with command line from eclipse : Could not initialize ideviceinstaller

Tags: eclipse, appium

First post.

Hi, I'm trying to run appium by executing the following command lines from eclipse:
`Process pr = rt.exec(new String[] {"/usr/local/bin/node", "/usr/local/bin/appium"});`
And then I run an AppiumDriver with the url and it's capabilities (also from eclipse): `AppiumDriver ad = new AppiumDriver(new URL(url), this.capabilities);`

These errors follow:

> - [36minfo[39m: [debug] Dynamic bootstrap path:
>     /Users/philippe.pageau/Library/Application
>     Support/appium/bootstrap/bootstrap-072528be314c3cc6.js
> - [36minfo[39m:
>     [debug] Reusing dynamic bootstrap:
>     /Users/philippe.pageau/Library/Application
>     Support/appium/bootstrap/bootstrap-072528be314c3cc6.js
> - [36minfo[39m:
>     [debug] Attempting iOS device log capture via libimobiledevice
>     idevicesyslog
> - [33mwarn[39m: Could not capture device log using
>     libimobiledevice idevicesyslog. Libimobiledevice probably isn't
>     installed
> - [36minfo[39m: [debug] Attempting iOS device log capture
>     via deviceconsole
> - [33mwarn[39m: Could not capture logs from device.
>     Continuing without capturing logs.
> - [36minfo[39m: [debug] Creating iDevice object with udid XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
> - [36minfo[39m: [debug] Couldn't find ideviceinstaller, trying
>     built-in at
>     /usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/build/libimobiledevice-macosx/ideviceinstaller
> - [36minfo[39m: [debug] Cleaning up appium session [36minfo[39m:
>     [debug] Error: Could not initialize ideviceinstaller; make sure it is
>     installed and works on your system
>
>   - at [object Object].IOS.getIDeviceObj (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/lib/devices/ios/ios.js:909:13)
>   - at [object Object].IOS.installToRealDevice (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/lib/devices/ios/ios.js:856:32)
>   - at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:607:21
>   - at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:246:17
>   - at iterate (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:146:13)
>   - at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:157:25
>   - at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:248:21
>   - at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:612:34
>   - at [object Object]. (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/lib/devices/ios/ios.js:1527:14)
>   - at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:890:21
>   - at [object Object]._onTimeout (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/lib/devices/ios/ios-log.js:166:7)
>   - at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:110:15)
> - [36minfo[39m: [debug] Responding to client with error: {"status":33,"value":{"message":"A
>     new session could not be created. (Original error: Could not
>     initialize ideviceinstaller; make sure it is installed and works on
>     your system)","origValue":"Could not initialize ideviceinstaller; make
>     sure it is installed and works on your system"},"sessionId":null}
> - [36minfo[39m: [37m<-- POST /wd/hub/session [39m[31m500[39m[90m
>     11133.802 ms - 300[39m [90m[39m
> - Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: A new session could
>     not be created. (Original error: Could not initialize
>     ideviceinstaller; make sure it is installed and works on your system)
>     (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
>     Command duration or timeout: 11.35 seconds

The errors show that it didn't find ideviceinstaller nor libimobiledevice (which I both installed)

I followed these instructions

> - [Appium throws "ideviceinstaller" not found when launched through Eclipse - Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29979589/appium-throws-ideviceinstaller-not-found-when-launched-through-eclipse-java)
> - http://technotesonthego.blogspot.ca/2013/10/install-libimobiledevice-on-mac-os-x.html

Note that I wish to execute everything from eclipse, allowing the QA to not worry about those things. It works with the GUI (I uninstalled it afterwards) and it also works when I run `appium` in the terminal and execute `AppiumDriver ad = new AppiumDriver(new URL(url), this.capabilities);` with eclipse.

I did my research, and asking the question to stackoverflow is my last resort.

Did I miss something?

**EDIT**
Also, I tried executing */usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/build/libimobiledevice-macosx/ideviceinstall‌​er* and it gave me this error : `dyld: Library not loaded: @executable_path/../lib/libimobiledevice.3.dylib Referenced from: /usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/build/libimobiledevice-macosx/ideviceinstalle‌​r Reason: image not found Trace/BPT trap: 5`

Comment: Is Libimobiledevice installed

Answer (score 0):

Tried on Appium 1.4.8:

- Step 1: install the "brew" command
- Step 2: run the following command: brew install --HEAD ideviceinstaller
- Step 3 (optional): click Appium/Reset Preferences and then close & open Appium

Good luck.